# How can insert data separately into pouchdb

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

How can I create two pouchdb .in run function? The method below will confuse between two pouchdb.

```
.run(function($pouchDB) {

$pouchDB.setDatabase("rowDB");
$.getJSON('test1.json', function(data) {
    var row = data[0].Rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        row[i]._id = row[i].id;
    }
    $pouchDB.bulkDocs(deprow);
});

$pouchDB.setDatabase("infoDB");
$.getJSON('test2.json', function(data) {
    var row = data[0].Rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        row[i]._id = row[i].id;
    }
    $pouchDB.bulkDocs(row); 
});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to move your setDatabase method call just before bulkDocs():

```
.run(function($pouchDB) {
$.getJSON('test1.json', function(data) {
    var row = data[0].Rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        row[i]._id = row[i].id;
    }
    $pouchDB.setDatabase("rowDB");
    $pouchDB.bulkDocs(deprow);
});
```